# Best way elevate the privileges programmatically under different versions of Linux?

Tags: linux, root

There is a standard way (working across Linux distributions) to launch a process (from another application) asking for the root password in order to elevate privileges?

I tried to use gksudo (it is installed in ubuntu by default), but under other distributions (or under other desktop manager) it may not be installed.

Comment: I might point out to the "not-programming-related" people that the linux/unix design philosophy is often to write very small single-purpose components that can be strung together via pipes or sockets.  Just because it's not a linkable API like in Windows, it's no less programming related in linux.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend looking at [PolicyKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolicyKit) which is what most modern distros are using to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

That works everywhere but does not cache the password and asks for the *root* and not the user password (as `sudo` does):

```
su - -c command
```

**EDIT**: Not on ubuntu where the *root*-account is disabled. Probably you need something like that:

```
test -x /usr/bin/sudo && sudo command || su - -c command
```

Comment: su - asks for root password and allows you to do anything, while sudo may be configured to ask user password and limit commands you're allowed to execute.

Comment: @vartec: The original question includes the text "asking for the root password in order to elevate privileges" which is precisely what su does.

Comment: Will not work on distributions like Ubuntu, where root is not permitted to log in interactively.

Answer (score 1):

The only default thing is text mode [**su**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)). Most distros have also [**sudo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) installed.

Now, in KDE based distros you'll have **kdesu**, while in GNOME based it'll be **gksu** and **gksudo**.  Machines in Kerberized domains have **ksu**.

You might try to use `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` to see which is the default desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, if your application needs to allow a user to elevate privileges, it installs its own single-purpose [`setuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executable -- single-purpose meaning that it performs the task needed, instead of acting as a general-purpose launcher.

```
$ su -
# cp `type -p id` /usr/local/bin/root-id
# chown root:users /usr/local/bin/root-id
# chmod 4750 /usr/local/bin/root-id
$ /usr/local/bin/root-id
... euid=0(root) ...
```

OTOH setuid executables have also been a common source of security holes too, so exercise care.