# Programmatically requesting elevated rights in Linux

Tags: linux, qt, root, maemo, root-access

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690463/best-way-elevate-the-privileges-programmatically-under-different-versions-of-linu) has identical title, but question body asks it in scripting point of view, e.g. `su -c`, don't dupe this to that)

I have a Qt GUI app that needs to perform some file operations in /etc based on user input. One option would probably to use `system()` with `sudo`, but even that requires messing with `sudoers` file in some point. I also would like not to do `system()` plus script hacks to modify the files, but proper file operations.

**What is the best way to programmatically elevate my applications rights to do this?**

Edit: as a bonus, it'd be nice if it would work on Maemo/Meego/other handhelds too (afaik PolicyKit isn't available there..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write a separate program altogether. Something along the lines of this [philosophy](http://cr.yp.to/qmail/guarantee.html). Basically - write a simple program that does exactly what you need, and control its behaviour with file permissions on the filesystem. Mainly,

> *Do as little as possible in setuid programs*.
>
> A setuid program must operate in a
>   very dangerous environment: a user is
>   under complete control of its fds,
>   args, environ, cwd, tty, rlimits,
>   timers, signals, and more. Even worse,
>   the list of controlled items varies
>   from one vendor's UNIX to the next, so
>   it is very difficult to write portable
>   code that cleans up everything.
>
> Of the twenty most recent sendmail
>   security holes, eleven worked only
>   because the entire sendmail system is
>   setuid.
>
> Only one qmail program is setuid:
>   qmail-queue. Its only purpose is to
>   add a new mail message to the outgoing
>   queue.

And,

> *Do as little as possible as root*.
>
> The entire sendmail system runs as
>   root, so there's no way that its
>   mistakes can be caught by the
>   operating system's built-in
>   protections. In contrast, only two
>   qmail programs, qmail-start and
>   qmail-lspawn, run as root.

Answer (score 4):

You could use PolicyKit, which is gradually superseding gksu/su/sudo, especially on Ubuntu, for its higher security and fine-grained control because of elevating *actions*, not the whole program.

Comment: PolicyKit looks excessively overcomplicated for such minor operation. Can you provide me an simple example (if such exists) how to achieve extra rights to modify a single file in /etc?

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper [setuid program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) that does only the things you want to do, and [fork / exec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) your application from it. Then drop privileges in the child process. Both applications could communicate over pipes, sockets, or something like that.

Have in mind that setuid programs are a security risk and so you should be very careful when implementing one.