# QT application rights for sudo command

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sudo

In my QT application i need to run some commands with sudo (like dd). Application is running under user. How can i switch rights (ask user for authorisation to run sudo) when application is running? Should i use PAM libraries or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just searching around for "elevate privileges" in linux, this is what I found.

[Best way elevate the privileges programmatically under different versions of Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690463/best-way-elevate-the-privileges-programmatically-under-different-versions-of-lin)

With an answer that pointed me here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolicyKit

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @wlredeye, can you please share how you solved your problem. I don't want uses to type password for every click of button.

Comment: @JeyKeu if you still interesting in solution, i've used a function that detect which kind of graphical su my system have (for example kdesu, gksu, etc...) and restart an application with this graphical su to get superuser privileges

Comment: @wlredeye Please post your solution as an answer below, which might help someone else. thanks.